# jQuery Tools Tabs - Named Anchors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, anchor

jQuery Tools Tabs v1.2 has me stuck on an issue. Let me show you the issue below.

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li><a href="#anchor">This is an item</a></li>
<li><a href="#anchor">This is an item</a></li>
<li><a href="#anchor">This is an item</a></li>
</ul>

<h1><a name="anchor></a>This Is The Header Where The Anchor Resides</h1>
<div class="panes">
<div>Here's the first item's content</div>
<div>Here's the second item's content</div>
<div>Here's the third item's content</div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is when you click on each item, you get dropped down to the new content, hence the new div appearing. Instead of just clicking away and not having your window locating to the top of the new DIV.

The problem? I have reason to believe that the jQuery Tools > Tabs Script automatically does a `return false;` somewhere within the plugin. Which is not allowing me to throw on any `href="#anchor"` within the link attribute. It's not showing up via the location of the window/page nor is it showing up on the Address Bar.

I would go directly to jQuery Tools' Forums and ask away, but their Forum/Support seems to be broke... Just like a good portion of the rest of the website, and of course Stack Overflow is ultimately better and has treated me a lot better in the past.

You may view the Tab System Here:
http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/index.html

You may view the Tab System Documentation Here:
http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tabs/index.html

You may view the Tab System jQuery/JavaScript Here:
http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: li has no attribute href

Comment: @EvilP: Thank you, I forgot the <a> tags when applying them to the StackOverFlow Question. Fixed! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{history : true}` option while initializing tabs

check this link
http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/history.html

Comment: Thank you sir, this ended up working out well, but the answer after yours was the answer. But, now, it has disappeared. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery().ready(function () {
         jQuery('ul.tabs a').click(function(){
                 jQuery(window).scrollTop( jQuery('a[name="anchor"]').position().top );
         });
}
```

Whomever it was that provided this answer a few minutes ago, and, I am assuming, deleted it. This was the answer! :). Thank you so much!

I am also running MODx with Friendly URLs. So this did the trick.